# Difference in usage between "variety " and "option"

Tags: single-word-requests

I recently read my English book and saw this sentence. "Claridge's has taken luxury to a new height by offering its guests more than 30 *varieties* of water - with prices stretching as much as 50 pounds a litre.

Why don't they use options?
It is stated that the restaurant has sold water from different places such as Norway, Patagonia, New Zealand and Hawaii.
Is this the reason why they use varieties?
If they use water from one same source and turn it into different kind of drinks , May I use option?

Comment: In English, you might be able to say "30 water options" and sound almost as natural as if you had said "30 varieties of water"—but "30 options of water" simply isn't an idiomatic form that native English speakers are at all likely to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that both are correct.

However, *varieties* implies that the selection we are speaking about contains objects which are all in the same class of objects, whereas *options* does not.

***Variety***

> a number or range of things of the same general class that are distinct in character or quality

***Option***

> a thing that is or may be chosen

In this case we know that we are taking about *water*, and so the implication is not necessary, and using *options* is fine.

While a *variety* does not imply that a thing may be chosen, we can gather this from the rest of the sentence and again this implication is not necessary.

They could also have gone for *choices*, but again this has the same implications has *options*

***Choice***

> a range of possibilities from which one or more may be chosen

Comment: Please mention by name the dictionary you quoted from. Also, if it's available online, do link to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

That definitely sounds like an issue of "sales fluff." You hit the nail on the head by noticing that they use "varieties" because it sounds awesome. You could you "options," but you may slightly confuse the reader. Part of the reason they use "varieties" is, as you mentioned, to indicate that the water comes in so many vastly different options. "Variety" also will indicate different categories or sorts, whereas "option" may be misconstrued as relating to sizes of waters, with or without lemon, and so forth.

va·ri·e·ty  vəˈrīədē
noun
the quality or state of being different or diverse; the absence of uniformity, sameness, or monotony.
a thing that differs in some way from others of the same general class or sort; a type.
sort kind type class category style form make model brand strain breed genus

op·tion  ˈäpSH(ə)n
noun
noun option plural noun options
a thing that is or may be chosen.
the freedom, power, or right to choose something.
choice alternative recourse course of action power to choose right to choose
a right to buy or sell a particular thing at a specified price within a set time.

Answer (score 0):

[Variety](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/variety) is used when referring to objects, and is synonymous with *kinds* or *types* when used this way. [Options](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/option) are choices a person *could* make, and is synonymous with choices or possibilities, in this usage.

The sentence referred to the water, rather than to the choosing of the water, or to those doing the selection. Options would be the ability the patrons would have to select from.

In order for options to be usable, the sentence would have to read:

> Claridge's has taken luxury to a new height by offering its guests more than 30 *different options **for*** water - with prices stretching as much as 50 pounds a litre.

Adding 'different' is needed to mark that Claridge's isn't offering water 30 times. 'For' replaces 'of' because 'options of water' is too close to another usage of 'options', usually regarding contracts or other legal issues.

Varieties is much more succinct, and makes the sentence more focused on the water.